# How can I prove the function is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

how can I determine if the conditioned function is convex? If so, how can I prove it?

The function is
$$
   f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{y^2}+y^2,\\y\geq\sqrt{x}\quad\text {and} \quad x>0,
$$
That's the question, I can't tell if it's convex.[![function figure over [0.1, 2]$\times$[0.1, 2] region,

Comment: The region is not convex so the question of convexity of the function does not arise.

Comment: But given any x, f(x,y) is increasing, and given any y, it is increasing, and both are convex,I don't understand why the whole is not.

Answer (score 1):

The line joining two points of the domain does not lie in the domain so the domain is not convex. Consequently your function is not convex.
[image]

Comment: Yes. you are right. I need to modify the condition. I forget the equality.

Comment: Sorry, for my mistake.

Comment: @Jack: Even with equality it is not going to work. Just pick two points on the lower border. Draw a line, it will not lie in the red region.